# Rails rake db:rollback on Heroku not working. Now I can't add any new migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I have an app that is working fine locally. At one point I tried installed the Act As Taggable gem, which generated a series of migration files. Now I rolled back locally after we voted against using that gem - but after deploying to heroku, it looks like 5 of these migration files did upload to heroku.

I then ran

```
`heroku run rake db:migrate'
```

I am now receiving this error

```
'uninitialized constant AddTaggingsCounterCacheToTags::ActsAsTaggableOn/app/db/migrate/20141107010718_add_taggings_counter_cache_to_tags.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb:6:in `up'
```

Now I don't need the  "AddTaggingsCounterCacheToTags" but I definitely need a migration that was supposed to run after this.

Any tips on how I can remove this from the production/heroku server? How I can remove only specific migrations and keep the newest migration I made?

Thanks!

Comment: Try with `heroku run rake db:schema:load`. But be careful! it will delete the data on the server

Comment: I have 100+ active users on the site. Will this affect any my current data? I just want to remove tables associated with a gem that is not in use.

Comment: Yes, it'll be deleted. You could follow this [approach](http://naturaily.com/blog/post/how-to-remove-old-database-migrations-in-ruby-on-rails). Basically you need to create a new migration from your schema without the `force: true` in the create table statement. With that approach your data will be safe

Comment: Hold on - this tutorial is great but running rake db:schema:load on my production server will remove all of our user data.

Comment: With that approach you are not running `rake db:schema:load`. Just creating the new migration from the schema. In your server you'll have to run just the migration

Comment: The problem you have is that you will have references to ActsAsTaggable in a migration and removing the gem breaks that migration. Put a fake class in the migration that matches the constant.

Comment: @JohnBeynon - I thought I had removed the migration files locally when pushing up and deploying so I can not edit them right now. Should I add them back in? My console...

Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:

 deleted:    db/migrate/20141107010716_acts_as_taggable_on_migration.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb
 deleted: ....

Comment: I've encounted similar problems before - note, it's note a Heroku specific problem - it's when you have application state (gems etc) referenced in migrations. To get myself out of the hole I think I edited the original migrations to make sure the class was present but then added a new migration to remove the tables.

Comment: Silly question @JohnBeynon - how to do I recover deleted files? I removed them from my machine and they read as "changes not staged for commit" - anyway I can add these original migration files back in and then add the class as you're suggesting?

Comment: Got it! Recovered the files. Where am I placing the fake class in this migration now?

Answer (score 1):

Okay folks. I got it.

The problem was that after I removed the files locally, they were still present on git. The process was to remove the migration that was causing the error and then I could have all migrations after come through just fine. Commands are below...

```
   git rm [filename]
   git commit -a -m "removed the migrations causing the error from git too"
   git push origin master
   git push heroku master
   heroku run rake db:migrate
```

There is an issue with having an empty/unnecessary table in the database now, but the important thing is - I can continue to add migrations and my newest features are now working properly on production!
Cheers!

Comment: @piratetome you can manually delete the table, with a SQL client.